# RNN in Tensorflow vs Keras, depreciation of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

My question is: Are the [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) and `keras.layers.RNN(cell)` truly identical as stated in docs?

I am planning on building an RNN, however, it seems that [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) is depricated in favour of Keras.

In particular, it states that:

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future
>   version. Instructions for updating: Please use keras.layers.RNN(cell),
>   which is equivalent to this API

But I don't see how the APIs are equivalent, in the case of variable sequence lengths!

In raw TF, we can specify a tensor of shape `(batch_size, seq_lengths)`. This way, if our sequence is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and the longest sequence in the batch is of size 10, we can pad it with 0s and `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, we can say `seq_length=5` to process `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

However, in Keras, this is not how it works! What we can do, is specify the `mask_zero=True` in previous Layers, e.g. the Embedding Layer. This will also mask the 1st zero!

I can go around it by adding ones to the whole vector, but then thats extra preprocessing that I need to do after processing using `tft.compute_vocabulary()`, which maps vocabulary words to 0 indexed vector.

Comment: are you talking about `keras` or `tf.keras`?

Comment: I question, whether you should really care about that (i.e. the previous `seq_lengths`). From the docs *...So it's more for performance than correctness.*

Comment: @MPękalski I use tf.keras

Comment: @rst I don't actually understand the issue about correctness. If I input the 0s, the matrix multiplication will also be 0, but then I will add a 1 bias which is passed through an activation function with it's weight. I will most likely get a non-zero output due to the bias term. Hence the bias weight will continue to train? Or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @rst Assuming they mean that there is no difference between passing the remaining 'padded' 0s into the RNN or masking them e.g. not training on them.

Comment: For now you can use `tf.keras.layers.Masking()` to dealt with it, but the thing is Masking is not supported `CuDNN RNN`. Probably the problem will be solved in TF. 2.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23269

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but they are (or can be made to be) not so different either.

### TL;DR

`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` replaces elements after the sequence end with 0s. This cannot be replicated with `tf.keras.layers.*` as far as I know, but you can get a similar behaviour with `RNN(Masking(...)` approach: it simply stops the computation and carries the last outputs and states forward. You will get the same (non-padding) outputs as those obtained from `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

### Experiment

Here is a minimal working example demonstrating the differences between [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) and [`tf.keras.layers.GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) with and without the use of [`tf.keras.layers.Masking`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking) layer.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

test_input = np.array([
    [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
], dtype=int)
seq_length = tf.constant(np.array([3, 4], dtype=int))

emb_weights = (np.ones(shape=(3, 2)) * np.transpose([[0.37, 1, 2]])).astype(np.float32)
emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    *emb_weights.shape,
    weights=[emb_weights],
    trainable=False
)
mask = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.37)
rnn = tf.keras.layers.GRU(
    1,
    return_sequences=True,
    activation=None,
    recurrent_activation=None,
    kernel_initializer='ones',
    recurrent_initializer='zeros',
    use_bias=True,
    bias_initializer='ones'
)


def old_rnn(inputs):
    rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        rnn.cell,
        inputs,
        dtype=tf.float32,
        sequence_length=seq_length
    )
    return rnn_outputs


x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=test_input.shape[1:])
m0 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=emb(x))
m1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=rnn(emb(x)))
m2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=rnn(mask(emb(x))))

print(m0.predict(test_input).squeeze())
print(m1.predict(test_input).squeeze())
print(m2.predict(test_input).squeeze())

sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()
print(sess.run(old_rnn(mask(emb(x))), feed_dict={x: test_input}).squeeze())
```

The outputs from `m0` are there to show the result of applying the embedding layer.
Note that there are no zero entries at all:

```
[[[1.   1.  ]    [[0.37 0.37]
  [2.   2.  ]     [1.   1.  ]
  [1.   1.  ]     [2.   2.  ]
  [0.37 0.37]     [1.   1.  ]
  [0.37 0.37]]    [0.37 0.37]]]
```

Now here are the actual outputs from the `m1`, `m2` and `old_rnn` architectures:

```
m1: [[  -6.  -50. -156. -272.7276 -475.83362]
     [  -1.2876 -9.862801 -69.314 -213.94202 -373.54672 ]]
m2: [[  -6.  -50. -156. -156. -156.]
     [   0.   -6.  -50. -156. -156.]]
old [[  -6.  -50. -156.    0.    0.]
     [   0.   -6.  -50. -156.    0.]]
```

### Summary

- The old `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` used to mask padding elements with zeros.
- The new RNN layers *without masking* run over the padding elements as if they were data.
- The new `rnn(mask(...))` approach simply stops the computation and carries the last outputs and states forward. Note that the (non-padding) outputs that I obtained for this approach are exactly the same as those from `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

Anyway, I cannot cover all possible edge cases, but I hope that you can use this script to figure things out further.

Comment: I expanded on this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264696/tensorflow-dynamic-rnn-deprecation) to show masking without an embedding layer. Great answer, this helped me a lot.

Comment: I made an interesting discovery this evening- if you wrap the GRU cell in a Bidirectional layer, it will convert the carried outputs to zero, therefore obtaining identical output to the old implementation without the necessity of predefined sequence lengths.